# Installation not proceed in ERPNext?

Tags: python, erpnext

I am trying to install ERPNext on my system at Ubuntu environment.but after 
python2.7 install_erpnext.py commond it stuck.

it said that it take time,i had wait for a day but process stucked at same position

please see the screenshot
[image]

Comment: i amalso stucked at the same point

Comment: Try to increase the memory size of your VM

Comment: install as non sudoer

Answer (score -1):

Try with these commands:

1. `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frappe/bench/master/playbooks/install.py`
2. Move to the root user :
   Try `sudo su` (16.04) or `su root`(<16.04)
3. `python install.py --develop --user frappe`(or your username)