# Stuck while installing ERPNext

Tags: erpnext

I am installing bench from https://github.com/frappe/bench. I have opted for the easy installation option. However, everytime the installation is getting stuck at [TASK] init bench. Any solutions?
[image: Relevant screenshot of the terminal during installation]

Comment: Please visit this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959287/installation-not-proceed-in-erpnext

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time in that step. 
If it shows error try to run the command using sudo:

```
sudo python install.py --develop --user frappe
```

Use erpnext forum for more help: [EPRNext Forum](http://discuss.erpnext.com)